# How do I deploy a VS2010 Web Site (Razor) to IIS7 on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7, razor, windows-server-2008, vs-web-site-project

I've created a new Application that points to the files. It is running in ASP.NET 4.0 Integrated App Pool.

The files are just a couple of CSHTML files and some CSS/Javascript.

When the files were HTML I was able to hit them just fine. Now that they are cshtml, I get

```
This type of page is not served
```

when I try to hit the Directory/File.cshtml in a browser.

I usually write MVC3 apps, but this is just a simple 2 page site that needs to be up. I'm not familiar with deployment of these types of projects. Any advice would be helpful.

My web.config is simple and looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
 </system.web>
<system.webServer>
<defaultDocument enabled="true">
  <files>
    <add value="MyFile.cshtml"/>        
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: > I'm not familiar with deployment of these types of projects.
But you have deployed MVC3 (Razor i presume) apps before ?

Comment: @wal Yes I've deployed Razor MVC3 apps before, just not "Web Site" projects.

Comment: Do you have MVC3 installed on your server? You can 'bin deploy'(http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx)  mvc3 but I find it cleaner to install it into the GAC if you have control over it. Then your web.config would need to change to wire it all up. I would suggest starting a new Blank asp.net mvc3 app (File -> New -> Project -> ASP.NET MVC3 Web Application) to generate the config file. I'm not suggesting you put your current files in the new project - use this only to get a web.config for a razor site.

Comment: MVC3 was installed, and I generated a web config, but I still couldn't hit the files. Ended up going with a MVC3 application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, install the "ASP.NET MVC 3 (Visual Studio 2010)" package using the "Web Platform Installer" (http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx).